# How to throttle installable trigger in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We use this code to set up `notify()` as a spreadsheet onEdit trigger function:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("notify").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
```

The above trigger `notify()` will notify the user by mail when a spreadsheet gets updated, but the problem is that it sends an email to the user for each and every edit. How do I overcome that, to send a single notification even if there are multiple changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal by remembering that you've notified a user, and suppressing further notifications (for a period of time). For example, this function uses the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to track notifications, and send just once per day:

```js
function notify(e) {
  // Get the date we last notified user
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var lastNotifyDate = properties.getProperty("lastNotified");

  // Get today's date
  var today = new Date().toDateString();

  // Should we send a notification to user?
  if (!lastNotifyDate || lastNotifyDate !== today) {

    // --- Place notification code here --- //

    // Notify user just once per day; remember we've sent a notification already
    properties.setProperty("lastNotified",today);
  }
}
```